# Why can't I get different users access my Flask app and get different data on the same page

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have a Flask app running all good with Flask-SQLAlchemy But the issue arises when I created multiple users and attempt to login at the same time.

Here's the scenario: lets say User A arrives on the login page and logs in and is redirected to the single-page web app where they have their names from a database displayed.

User B arrives on the login page and logs in and is redirected to the single-page web app where they have their information from a database displayed.

User A refreshes their page and comes to find that they're logged in as User B and are able to view the name of User B.

Is there a way to prevent this/allow both users to be logged in without kicking the other user off? I have been using Flask-login that didn't solve either. Help me out.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request , redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required
import random
import string


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///mydb.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_Manager = LoginManager()
login_Manager.init_app(app)
login_Manager.login_view = 'login'



class Accounts(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    User_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    Email = db.Column(db.String(75), nullable = False)
    Password = db.Column(db.String(75), nullable = False)
    session_token = db.Column(db.String(40), index=True) 
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)

    def get_id(self):                                                           
        return str(self.session_token)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.Name)

@login_Manager.user_loader
def load_user(session_token):
    return Accounts.query.filter_by(session_token = session_token).first()
    

@app.route('/login/', methods=["POST","GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_name = request.form['username']
        user_password = request.form['password']
        all_accounts = Accounts.query.all()
        for account in all_accounts:
            if account.User_name == user_name and account.Password == user_password:
                N = 40
                tokk = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(N))
                
                luser = Accounts.query.get(account.id)
                luser.session_token = tokk
                db.session.commit()
                
                user = Accounts.query.get(account.id)
                login_user(user)
                global name_user
                name_user =  Accounts.query.get(user_id)
                return redirect('/Home')
        return """<h1>Something Happened While logging you in <h1> <a href="/login">Retry</a>"""
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/Home')
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('Home.html', NAME = name_user )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'thismysecretekey'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And my home page..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div >

        <p>Logged as: <b>{{ NAME }}</b></p>
        <hr class="popline">
        <br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using global variables in Flask - Not recommended at all, and that causes your issue. You see, when a user signs in, you programmed the code to put as the `"name_user"` to the user who just signed in. that's why it changes the user every time a new user logs in to the site. Luckily you are using flask-login so you can simply use `current_user.Name` to get the name of the user who is currently logged in.

So in summary:

insted of:

```
return render_template('Home.html', NAME = name_user )
```

do:

```
return render_template('Home.html', NAME = current_user.Name)
```

and don't forget to import `current_user` from `flask_login`

```
from flask_login import current_user
```